# Echo PHP Code within an HTML string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to display a lump of HTML text by a template variable and it seems to not be processing the PHP. I currently use this in my view (this is codeigniter)

```
<?php dump($_SESSION); echo (isset($html) && !empty($html)) ? $html : show_404(); ?>
```

The HTML includes a couple locations with php tags and I'd like those to get loaded when the page is echo'd. Is there a way to do this?

The main reason I need it to work from the HTML variable I pass in is because this is part of a page creator and I need to be able to plop php conditions in there that aren't in every page.

Comment: So the `$html` variable is a string which contains `<?php ...` code, and you want that code to be executed?

Comment: Sounds like you want to [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) something, which means you probably have something more fundamentally wrong with your design. `eval() === √evil` - **do not do it!**

Comment: `isset($var) && !empty($var)` → `!empty($var)` - you don't need the redundant `isset` there.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do it, but it's bad: `eval()`

```
echo (isset($html) && !empty($html)) ? eval($html) : show_404();
```

Comment: eval will *not* work if the contents of `$html` is template-like (i.e. has `<?php` in it)

Comment: Someone upvoted what is considered an "evil" in programming and something that shouldn't work for this question? hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

I would personally `ob` this from a file, buffering it and then use `get_ob_clean` to get the result, like so:

```
    ob_start();
        include 'temp_file_with_html_in';
        $view = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Note:

- Your English is unclear so I am not sure exactly what you want
- This may not work exactly as you want

Maybe a better explanation of what `$html` is and how it is sourced would help?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I can think of (though a better solution could likely be found if I knew *how* `$html` was created) is to plop the contents into a tmp file and then include it. This is really a warning flag that there are architectural problems with the program, however (for instance, why can't the php interpolation be done when $html is created?)

```
$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'my_app_namespace');
file_put_contents($tmpFile, $html);
include $tmpFile;
unlink($tmpFile); // cleanup
```

## edit, from Drupal 7

As you hinted in the comment, Drupal 7 does indeed contain what I would call a trick: prepending a PHP *closing* tag to the code you pass to `eval`, which will then handle it like a regular php include:

From Drupal 7's ./modules/php/php.module, around line 79, adapted a bit:

```
ob_start();
print eval('?>' . $html);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: That could work, but I'm curious how Drupal does it. They use a similar thing with their article posting.

Comment: I found something interesting in Drupal 7, not sure if it's what they use in the feature you mentioned, but it might be more in line with what you were expecting...

Comment: Note, hoever, that Drupal's ./includes/ folder contains many ardent comments urging folks *not* to use eval...